# require_owner code to limit controller actions not recognizing current user as owner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [before_filter :require_owner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460650/before-filter-require-owner)

I am trying to restrict access to certain actions using a before_filter which seems easy enough. Somehow the ApplicationController is not recognizing that the current_user is the owner of the user edit action. When I take the filter off the controller correctly routes the current_user to their edit view information. Here is the code.

Link to call edit action from user controller (`views/questions/index.html.erb`):

```
<%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_path(:current) %>
```

ApplicationController (I am only posting the code that I think is affecting this but can post the whole thing if needed).

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    def require_owner
          obj = instance_variable_get("@#{controller_name.singularize.camelize.underscore}") # LineItem becomes @line_item
          return true if current_user_is_owner?(obj)
          render_error_message("You must be the #{controller_name.singularize.camelize} owner to access this page", root_url)
          return false
        end
 end
```

and the before_filter

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

before_filter :require_owner, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy]

#...

end
```

I simply get the rendering of the error message from the ApplicationController#require_owner action.

UPDATE: the link_to provides this address: localhost:3000/users/current/edit

Comment: how does `edit_user_path(:current)` link look like?

Comment: Good question. Like this: http://localhost:3000/users/current/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is the second bounty question that I have posted and then answered myself. Both times I have found the answer within an hour of my bounty post. Ha.

I simply changed the before filter method to get this to work. I left the application controller as it is in the code above but in the UsersController (the only one that wasn't cooperating) I did the following:

```
    before_filter :require_user, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy]  # all actions require user to be logged in
    before_filter :init_data     # create a member variable called @post, initialized based on the action
    before_filter :require_user_owner, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy] #edit, update, and destroy actions require ownership
```

and then

```
private

    def require_user_owner
      obj = instance_variable_get("@#{controller_name.singularize.camelize.underscore}") # LineItem becomes @line_item
      return true if current_user.id == @user.id
      render_error_message("You must be the #{controller_name.singularize.camelize} owner to access this page", root_url)
      return false
    end
```

That seemed to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the `current_user_is_owner?(obj)` call have an issue. To prove it, modify the code to:

```
def require_owner
  # LineItem becomes @line_item
  obj = instance_variable_get("@#{controller_name.singularize.camelize.underscore}") 
  if current_user_is_owner?(obj)
    return true
  else
    render_error_message("You must be the #{controller_name.singularize.camelize} owner to access this page", root_url)
    return false
  end
end
```

You might want to paste the `current_user_is_owner?` method.

Hopefully it helps.

Comment: I replaced the require_owner code in the application controller with the code you provided above but didn't work. Same result as the other code. Perhaps the problem is in the link itself.